# Deploying package using command line fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msdeploy, web-deployment

What I've done:

1, Created a new Mvc Application project.

2, Build a deployment package using Visual Studio

3, Run this command in command the line

```
C:\TEMP\packages\MvcApplication6.deploy.cmd /t
```

and it crashes with this output

```
C:\Users\Fabik>C:\TEMP\packages\MvcApplication6.deploy.cmd /t
=========================================================
SetParameters from:
"C:\TEMP\packages\MvcApplication6.SetParameters.xml"
You can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, connectionString
or other deploy parameters in the above file.
-------------------------------------------------------
 Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
 "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C
:\TEMP\packages\MvcApplication6.zip' -dest:auto,includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -
disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:Certific
ateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\TEMP\packages\MvcApplication6.SetParameters.xml"
 -whatif

Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configur
ation system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsE
xception: Unrecognized configuration section startup. (C:\Program Files\IIS\Micr
osoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe.Config line 2)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Intern
al.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sect
ionName)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners()
   at System.Diagnostics.Trace.get_Listeners()
   at MSDeploy.CommandLineTraceListener.EnableCommandLineTraceListeners()
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.Main(String[] unusedArgs)
```

When I use the IIS manager to import the package it works fine. What could be the problem ? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

That error message looks like the .NET 2 CLR is executing msdeploy.exe. Try (re-)installing .NET 4.0 Full Profile.